# PowerBI DAX - Calculate, CountRows, RelatedTable, get TOP 1

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following PowerBI DAX Measure. It has to be this complex for a number of reasons due to the structure of the data. The measure works fine, and it returns me the number of active contracts for each customer. This displays nicely on a visual grid and gives a total of all the active contracts for all the customers.

```
ActiveContracts = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(RELATEDTABLE(Contracts)), 
FILTER(Contracts,
        (
        Contracts[StartDate] >= CALCULATE(MIN(DateRange[Date]), ALLEXCEPT(DateRange, DateRange[Date])) && 
        Contracts[StartDate] <= CALCULATE(MAX(DateRange[Date]), ALLEXCEPT(DateRange, DateRange[Date]))
        )       
        ||
        (
        Contracts[End Date] >= CALCULATE(MIN(DateRange[Date]), ALLEXCEPT(DateRange, DateRange[Date])) && 
        Contracts[End Date] <= CALCULATE(MAX(DateRange[Date]), ALLEXCEPT(DateRange, DateRange[Date]))
       )
       ||
       (
       Contracts[StartDate] <= CALCULATE(MIN(DateRange[Date]), ALLEXCEPT(DateRange, DateRange[Date])) && 
       Contracts[End Date] >= CALCULATE(MAX(DateRange[Date]), ALLEXCEPT(DateRange, DateRange[Date]))
       )
   )     
)
```

However, I only need the first result, or even more simply, just the fact that there is a result (i.e. an active contract for a customer).

I have tried a number of things and the closest I can get is another measure on top of the one above:

```
HasContract = CALCULATE(IF(ISBLANK([CCActiveContract]), 0, 1))
```

This then works on the row level, but when I total the column with this new measure, it gives a total of 1, whereas I want a count of all customers with an active contract?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by Tom Martens over on the PowerBI forum ([link](http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/PowerBI-DAX-Calculate-CountRows-RelatedTable-get-TOP-1/m-p/274660#M122745)) using:

```
ContractPerCustomer = SUMX(Customer, IF([ActiveContracts] > 0, 1, 0))
```